# How can I merge(concatenate) 2 lists?

Tags: c++

This is my code to concatenate to lists, but for some reason after it does so it ends up in a loop and doesn't stop.

```
  void concatenate(){
        p2 = first2;
        while (p2 != NULL) {
            p = new list;
            p->data = p2->data2;
            last->next = p;
            last = p;
            p2 = p2->next2;
        }
    }
```

data - the information of the first list
data2 - the information of the second list
last - a pointer from the first list
p - pointer from the first list
p2 - pointer from the second list

Comment: Why are you creating a new list in a function to concatenate?

Comment: @aschpler I'm adding a new node for the first list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 void concatenate(){

        last->next = first2; // done

  }

  //if not the same type or cannot be casted


   void concatenate(){
        if ( first2 == null ){
             last->next = 0;
             return;
         }

        last->next = new list(first2->data2); //connect the lists
        first2=first2->next;
        last=last->next;

        while( first2->next ) // copy the values
        {
            last->next = new list(first2->data2); 
            first2=first2->next;
            last=last->next;

        }
        last->next=0;
  }
```

Comment: I tried something liked that but for some reason it says that it cannot convert "list2" to "list". Maybe because the pointer "first2" is used in the first list?

Comment: they are not the same type, are they derived from one another? Can you post the declaration for list and list2?

Comment: `struct list {
    int data;
    list * next;
};
list * p, * first, * last;
//int ok;            

                
struct list2 {
    int data2;
    list2 * next2;
};`